# Index exceeds matrix dimensions while using ode45

Tags: matlab, ode

I am trying to solve an ode using ode45 and it is showing.

```
function ydot=vdpol(t,y) 
t=0; 
y=0; 
mu=2;
ydot=[y(2);mu*(1-y(1)^2)*y(2)-y(1)]; 
tspan=[0 20]; y0=[2;0]; 
[t,y]=ode45(vdpol,tspan,y0);
size(t) 
size(y) 
plot(t,y(:,1),t,y(:,2),'--'); 
xlabel('time'); 
title('van der pol solution')
```

Comment: Can you explain what do are willing to achieve and what problems you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
ydot=[y(2);mu*(1-y(1)^2)*y(2)-y(1)];
```

you just tried to refer to second element of `y` but it's not an array:

```
whos y
Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

y         1x1                 8  double
```

Next: you don't use `ydot` any further so I suppose you don't need it!
Next: you use `vdpol` without any definition of this function or variable.

Here is a right solution (that is not my code. It's from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/differential-equations.html)):

```
tspan = [0, 20];
y0 = [2; 0];
Mu = 1;
ode = @(t,y) vanderpoldemo(t,y,Mu);
[t,y] = ode45(ode, tspan, y0);

% Plot of the solution
plot(t,y(:,1))
xlabel('t')
ylabel('solution y')
title('van der Pol Equation, \mu = 1')
```